# Adding "restrictions" to a context free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I'm trying to construct a context free grammar from the following definition:

```
L = {a^n b^m : 0 <= n <= m <= 2n}
```

I tried to divide it on steps, so I first made a CFG for the first two conditions (L = {a^n b^m : 0 <= n <= m}) but I can't seem to "limit" the number of b's to a maximum of the double of the number of a's. Any idea?

Comment: `L -> a L b | a L b b | ε` seems straightforward.

Comment: @rici I don't think that's right, what if I tried to have 2 a's and 3 b's? the grammar you commented doesn't allow that.

Comment: yes, it does. `L (1) -> a L b (2) -> a a L b b b (3) -> a a b b b`. Number before `->` indicates which replacement for L to use.

Comment: Each recursive production adds exactly one `a` and either one or two `b`s. So the number of `b`s can't be less than the number of `a`s nor can it be more than twice as great.